# What is the Swift equivalent of C++'s std::map?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to use map/set in Swift.

In C++, I would write the code as follows:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::map<long long, int> f;  // declare

    // insert some elements
    f[100000000000000LL] = 1;

    printf("%d\n", f[100000000000000LL]);

    return 0;
}
```

How would I implement this in Swift?

Comment: Swift does not have a built-in equivalent of `std::map`. It has an equivalent of `std::unordered_map`, which is a dictionary.

Comment: Not sure why there's such a downvote (-7). It is perfectly reasonable to wonder about sorted containers. Now if Swift would provide those straight out of the box, this question would deserve a downvote, but Swift dictionaries are unsorted.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, unordered is not I need.

Comment: @MSalters, Swift doesn't have a balanced BST in Standard library? I need this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift the map its called Dictionary.

You need a dictionary of CLong  so:

```
var f = [CLong: CLong]()
f[100000000000000] = 1
```

then you only need to println the content of the dictionary.

Comment: `Dictionary` in Swift is like a `std::unordered_map<CLong, CLong>` in c++ (based on hash table). While `std::map` in c++ is a balanced BST. I do not understand why this answer is marked as correct one.

Comment: denys is right - A dictionary is a type of hash table in swift: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

If you want a Map, you need to implement a BST and keep tabs of the indexes, for supporting Ordering. Map, in the aspect of Ordering, is faster that Hash-Map (as in unordered_map in STL), but Hash-Map is much faster in search time than Map.